# permalinks got %20 in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom portfolio page for my client. I'm using the Bridge wordpress theme. The problem is when I view my portfolio items from backend editor by clicking "view post" it looks like: http://jk.beta.indesigner.co/%20/shanes-cabana-bar/

but when I view this exact portfolio item from portfolio page, it looks like:
http://jk.beta.indesigner.co//shanes-cabana-bar/

"%20" gone!! so the portfolio items are not loading from frontpage by click IMG the title. How can I solve it?

I'm using this for my title:

```
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
```

I should mention it, this problem occurs only if I activate pretty permalinks through backend... if I use the default one everything works fine!

Comment: %20 is a space character, so what did you expect?

Comment: The real question is, why would you have spaces in your URL's ?

Comment: Give the url some space, it needs its privacy.

Comment: the problem is I don't have any space in my url.

Comment: But you do. What is the contents of `the_permalink()` function?

Comment: I'm using a theme from market place, I didn't build it.

Comment: when I create a portfolio item, it automatically creates an extra backslash like this:  `http://jk.beta.indesigner.co/ /shanes-cabana-bar/`
but it should be like this:  `http://jk.beta.indesigner.co/shanes-cabana-bar/`

Comment: If you don't want to have the space in there, why did you put it in?

Comment: man exactly, I did not put any kind of space. it is automatically generated!

Comment: I should mention it, this problem occurs only if I activate pretty permalinks through backend... if I use the default one everything works fine!

Comment: @Aohor Arsalan: Rename the plugin folder and set the theme to default - does it still happen? And are you sure you didn't enter the space in the pretty permalinks?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be coming from empty space after your domain name:

> "yourdomain.com "
> instead of:
> "yourdomain.com"

I had an issue with fonts not displaying properly and I have noticed that I accidently put an empty space after the URL and in the browser, the URL was displayed with %20 added at the end.